# Incorrect syntax near insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect syntax near insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198369/incorrect-syntax-near-insert)

For some reason I can't get the tables populated.  It worked before but I don't know why it won't run now.

```
CREATE DATABASE Mort;
Go


USE Mort;
-----------------------------------
/*
**This script creates the  
** Employee table with the foreign key
*/
-----------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------
/* I chose Job_title as the PRIMARY KEY.
**All rows must be unique. There is a Job_title
**column in the Employee table that can be used as a 
**foreign key. 
*/
/*
**This script creates the  
** Job title table
*/
----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE 
Job_title
(Job_title varchar (50) PRIMARY KEY,
EEO_1_Classification varchar(200),
Job_description varchar(250),
Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status bit );
Go

CREATE TABLE 
Employee
(Emp_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY,  
Last_name varchar(25),      
First_name varchar(25),
Address varchar(40),        
City varchar (15),
State char(2),
Telephone_area_code varchar(3),     
Telephone_number varchar(8),        
Job_title varchar(50) foreign key references job_title(job_title),  
Hire_date smalldatetime,    
Wage money,
Gender char(1),
Race varchar(25),
Age int );
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* (3.1) This script inserts employee records 
** for both the administrative offices 
** and the Del Mar location  
*/
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

USE Mort;
Go


INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('McNamara',
'Juanita',
'923 Parkway',
'La Jolla',
'CA',
'619',
'555-0208',
'Accounting Clerk',
'10/07/2003',
'$12.75',
'F',
'Hispanic',
32);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES
('Stephens',
'Harvey',
'7863 High Bluff Drive',
'La Jolla',
'CA',
'619',
'555-0123',
'Dir. of Fin.
& Acct.',
'3/1/1998',
'$75,000.00',
'M',
'Caucasian',
51);

INSERT INTO 
Employee

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,  
Hire_date,  
Wage,       
Gender,     
Race,           
Age)

VALUES
('Vu',
'Matthew',
'981 Torrey Pines Road',
'La Jolla',
'CA',
'619',
'555-0138',
'Computer Support Specialist',
'8/16/2000',
'$18.50',
'M',
'Asian',
26);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Nguyen',
'Meredith',
'10583 Arenas ST. ',
'La Jolla ',
'CA',
'619',
'555-0102',
'Computer Support Specialist ',
'9/27/1998 ',
'$21.50 ',
'M',
'Caucasian',
25);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Avery',
'Ledonna',
'198 Governor Dr.',
'Del Mar',
'CA',
'619',
'555-0135',
'Asst. - Bakery & Pastry',
'3/28/2003',
'$10.50',
'F',
'African American',
23);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Drohos',
'Craig',
' ',
'Selano Beach',
'CA',
'619',
'555-0202',
'Assistant Manager',
'6/15/2000',
'$51,000.00 ',
'M',
'Caucasian',
32);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Meier',
'Elaine',
'9703 Orchid Lane',
'Del Mar',
'CA',
'858',
'555-0112',
'Cashier',
'9/10/2000',
'$10.25',
'F',
'Asian',
51);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Quillian',
'Stanley',
'98542 Wandering Road Apt 2-B',
'Del Mar',
'CA',
'760',
'555-0198',
'Asst. - Butchers & Seafood Specialists',
'12/16/1999',
'$11.50 ',
'M',
'American Indian',
29);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Tyink',
'Thomas',
'87592 Pacific Heights Blvd.',
'Del Mar',
'CA',
'858',
'555-0159',
'Asst. - Bakery & Pastry',
'5/1/2001',
'$9.50',
'M',
'African American',
32);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Vance',
'Brent',
'927 Cynthia Lane Parkway',
'Del Mar',
'CA',
'858',
'555-0147',
'Bagger - 30 hours/wk',
'3/29/2001',
'$6.75',
'M',
'Caucasian',
22);


------------------------------------------------------
/* This script inserts values into Job_title table
** Note: 1 means exempt (salaried)
**  0 means non-exempt (hourly)
** Section (2.2)
*/
------------------------------------------------------



INSERT INTO Job_title
(Job_title, EEO_1_Classification, Job_description, Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status )
VALUES
('Accounting Clerk', 'Office/Clerical', 
'Computes, classifies, records, and verifies numerical data for use in maintaining
accounting records.',
0);

INSERT INTO Job_title
(Job_title, EEO_1_Classification, Job_description, Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status )
VALUES
('Assistant Manager', 'Officials & Managers',
'Supervises and coordinates activities of workers in department of food store.
Assists store manager in daily operations of store.' ,
1);

INSERT INTO Job_title
(Job_title, EEO_1_Classification, Job_description, Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status )
VALUES
('Bagger','Sales Workers',
'Places customer orders in bags. Performs carryout duties for customers.',
0);

INSERT INTO Job_title
(Job_title, EEO_1_Classification, Job_description, Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status )
VALUES
('Cashier','Sales Workers',
'Operates cash register to itemize and total customer’s purchases in grocery
store.',
0);

INSERT INTO Job_title
(Job_title, EEO_1_Classification, Job_description, Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status )
VALUES
('Computer Support Specialist','Technician',
'Installs, modifies, and makes minor repairs to personal computer hardware and
software systems, and provides technical assistance and training to system
users.',
0);

INSERT INTO Job_title
(Job_title, EEO_1_Classification, Job_description, Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status )
VALUES
('Dir. of Fin. & Acct.','Officials & Managers',
'Plans and directs the finance and accounting activities for Kudler Fine Foods.',
1);

INSERT INTO Job_title
(Job_title, EEO_1_Classification, Job_description, Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status )
VALUES
('Asst. - Bakery & Pastry','Craft Workers (Skilled)',
'Obtains or prepares food items requested by customers in retail food store.',
0);

INSERT INTO Job_title
(Job_title, EEO_1_Classification, Job_description, Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status )
VALUES
('Asst. - Butchers & Seafood Specialists','Operatives (Semi skilled)',
'Obtains or prepares food items requested by customers in retail food store.',
0);

INSERT INTO Job_title
(Job_title, EEO_1_Classification, Job_description, Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status )
VALUES
('Stocker','Office/Clerical',
'Stores, prices and restocks merchandise displays in store.',
0)





------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
**(3.2) This script Checks the results by selecting  
**all of the columns from both of the tables 
**Select * from
**Select * from
*/ 
/*
**Format of Employee table due to requirement
**Do not “string out” an entire query/statement so 
**that it requires the viewer to horizontally scroll to read it.
*/
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




USE Mort;

Select Emp_id, Last_name, First_name, Address, City, State from Employee
Go

Select Telephone_area_code, Telephone_number, Job_title, Hire_date, Wage, Gender, Race, Age from Employee
Go

Select * from Job_title
Go

/*
**(3.3)  Write a SQL query that joins two tables in the example database and uses BETWEEN **to restrict record selection. (Use salary to restrict the data.)
*/


Select Employee.Wage, Job_title.Job_title
From Employee
inner join  Job_title
on Employee.Wage=Job_title.Job_title
order by Employee.Last_name
```

(3.4)  Write a SQL query that joins two tables in the example database and uses BETWEEN to restrict record selection. (Use hire dates to restrict the data.)
(3.5)  Write a SQL query that joins two tables in the example database and uses LIKE to restrict record selection. (Use telephone area codes to restrict data.)
(3.6)  Write a SQL query that joins two tables in the example database and uses LIKE to restrict record selection. (Use age to find all people in their 20’s.)
(3.7)  Write a SQL query that uses UNION of the two tables.  Be creative.

(3.8)  Write a SQL query that displays the average salary / hourly wage grouped by job_title.
(3.9)  Write a SQL query that displays the number of people in each EE0-1 Classification and the average salary / hourly wage for each classification.
(3.10)  Group employees by EEO classification: Select the employees’ last names and group them by EEO-1 Classification
(3.11)  Group employees by salary within their EEO classification: Select the employees’ last names and group them by salary within their EEO-1 Classification. 
(3.12)  Select the employees’ last names and group them by salary within job titles that are grouped into exempt and non-exempt.

Comment: If you format your question a bit better and cut out any irrelevant text then you might have better luck in responses. Also, if this is homework, please tag it as such. Finally, are you getting an error? What is that error?

Comment: in the insert error it would have told you something specific about the  error that could lead you to the insert command that is having a problem...some of the text it was trying to insert or something.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a VALUES section for one of the INSERT's(the 6th INSERT)