# Incorrect syntax near insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a student this is homework...
The tables are there but data isn't being inserted.

Thanks for any advice

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 181
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'.
```

SQL statement:

```
USE Mort;
Go


INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('McNamara',
'Juanita',
'923 Parkway',
'La Jolla',
'CA',
'619',
'555-0208',
'Accounting Clerk',
'10/07/2003',
'$12.75',
'F',
'Hispanic',
32);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES
('Stephens',
'Harvey',
'7863 High Bluff Drive',
'La Jolla',
'CA',
'619',
'555-0123',
'Dir. of Fin.
& Acct.',
'3/1/1998',
'$75,000.00',
'M',
'Caucasian',
51);

INSERT INTO 
Employee
 
(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,  
Hire_date,  
Wage,       
Gender,     
Race,           
Age)

VALUES
('Vu',
'Matthew',
'981 Torrey Pines Road',
'La Jolla',
'CA',
'619',
'555-0138',
'Computer Support Specialist',
'8/16/2000',
'$18.50',
'M',
'Asian',
26);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Nguyen',
'Meredith',
'10583 Arenas ST. ',
'La Jolla ',
'CA',
'619',
'555-0102',
'Computer Support Specialist ',
'9/27/1998 ',
'$21.50 ',
'M',
'Caucasian',
25);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Avery',
'Ledonna',
'198 Governor Dr.',
'Del Mar',
'CA',
'619',
'555-0135',
'Asst. - Bakery & Pastry',
'3/28/2003',
'$10.50',
'F',
'African American',
23);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Drohos',
'Craig',
' ',
'Selano Beach',
'CA',
'619',
'555-0202',
'Assistant Manager',
'6/15/2000',
'$51,000.00 ',
'M',
'Caucasian',
32);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Meier',
'Elaine',
'9703 Orchid Lane',
'Del Mar',
'CA',
'858',
'555-0112',
'Cashier',
'9/10/2000',
'$10.25',
'F',
'Asian',
51);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Quillian',
'Stanley',
'98542 Wandering Road Apt 2-B',
'Del Mar',
'CA',
'760',
'555-0198',
'Asst. - Butchers & Seafood Specialists',
'12/16/1999',
'$11.50 ',
'M',
'American Indian',
29);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Tyink',
'Thomas',
'87592 Pacific Heights Blvd.',
'Del Mar',
'CA',
'858',
'555-0159',
'Asst. - Bakery & Pastry',
'5/1/2001',
'$9.50',
'M',
'African American',
32);

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Vance',
'Brent',
'927 Cynthia Lane Parkway',
'Del Mar',
'CA',
'858',
'555-0147',
'Bagger - 30 hours/wk',
'3/29/2001',
'$6.75',
'M',
'Caucasian',
22);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incorrect syntax near insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198194/incorrect-syntax-near-insert)

Comment: Since this one is formatted a bit better, I already voted to close the other question.

Comment: Please indicate which database and database client you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an `INSERT INTO Employee...` in there without a `VALUES` clause (The one after "Ledonna")

Note if you double click on the error message in Management Studio it should take you to the problem bit of code.

Answer (score 2):

There's your problem:

```
INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

INSERT INTO 
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
Job_title,
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age)

VALUES 
('Drohos',
'Craig',
' ',
'Selano Beach',
'CA',
'619',
'555-0202',
'Assistant Manager',
'6/15/2000',
'$51,000.00 ',
'M',
'Caucasian',
32);
```

Look at the error message, at line 181.

You need to have values with your insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a value block:

```
Hire_date,
Wage,
Gender, 
Race,
Age) -- MISSING VALUES HERE

INSERT INTO -- THIS IS LINE 181
Employee 

(Last_name,
First_name,
Address,
City,
State,
Telephone_area_code,
Telephone_number,
```

find the "Go to line" option in your editor it will help you to find the wrong line